# How to update context in EF Core without ForEach?

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I am getting some data from my database:

```
var productCollections = _context.ProductCollections 
   .Include(pc => pc.Products)
   .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductDetails)
   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productCollectionId);
```

With the products in the collection I am getting some product-details from a different backend and safe that data in a List<> containing the product-number and the details. I want to add these details to a List<> named ProductDetails in the products.

```
productCollection.Products.ForEach(p => p.ProductDetails.AddRange(
    foundProductDetailsList
        .Where(d => d.RequestedProductNumber == p.ProductNumber)
        .Select(x => new StaticPartBasketItemFound
        {
            DetailX = x.DetailX,
            DetailY = x.DetailY
        })));
```

Both may contain 100.000 items and it's pretty slow to perform the code above.

Is there any chance to "join-update" the "ProductDetails" within my "productCollection.Products" or similar fast methods?

I am using .NET 5.0.3 and EF-Core.

Comment: is `foundProductDetailsList` in memory or an `IQueryable`?

Comment: After adding the details to `ProductDetails` list, how the `productCollection` is going to be used? I mean, is it in a web application where the final data collection is sent to the client and the context is disposed?

Comment: @DStanley : It's the result from another rest-service which is a List<> in memory.

Comment: @atiyar : I want to write back the results back to the DB, so I'm using _context.SaveContext(); which is suprisingly fast enough. The whole code is running with Hangfire asynchronous in the background, but the faster, the better.

Comment: @Stix I asked because if you were to send the data to client-side then you could perform the operation turning change tracking off which would increase the performance significantly. But since you are going to save the data back to DB of course you'll be needing the change tracking in place.

Comment: @atiyar : Sure, good question, but saving the changes is the main target.

Comment: You can turn off `DetectChanges` status synchronization:
`context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`
//Manually synchronize the status after performing the operation
`context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();`